# List with version information

Tags: 2013, versioning

Here is the scenario.

- List A: versioning enable
- List B: Store all the versions of the items in List A

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes? Enable versioning on list B and copy items from A into B? Or are you wanting to see List B as individual line items per version?

Comment: Why do you need a List B if list A has versioning enabled?

Comment: List B should hold version history of List A

Comment: But SharePoint has its own version control system. No need to save versions in another list.

Comment: i do know that, i want to see the possibility of the above scenario